# Flag "yes/No" if the subsequent row has same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like this. If the same id is present in the next row, I want to flag as Yes. If it is not present then Make it as 'No'. Can you kindly help me with the query?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: avoid images. try to put them as textual data.

Comment: SQL table have no default row order (in terms of logical storage, not physical). So there's no *previous* row unless you have an ordering column(s). What will be the output for spreadsheet rows like ```1, 2, 2, 1, 1```?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with multiple rows for the same ID and no other column that can be used to futher narrow the sort sequence is that you need an order you can rely on. As the typical sulution for the general task to compare with the next row's ID is `LEAD`, you'll have two `ORDER BY` clauses in your query, one for `LEAD` and one for the query result, and you want to force them somehow to obey the same sort order. `ORDER BY id` is not sufficent.

The best and easiest approach is probably to number the rows first, and then work on this data set.

```
with numbered
(
  select
    id,
    row_number() over (order by id) as rn
  from mytable
)
select
  id,
  case when id = lead(id) over (order by rn) then 'yes' else 'no' end as flag
from numbered
order by rn;
```

Comment: This answer looks elegant and logical. The difference between a junior Dev and senior Dev can be understood by looking at this answer and the answer I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEAD`, which gets the value of the next row.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
       WHEN ID = LEAD(ID) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN 'yes'
       ELSE 'no'
    END
FROM [MyTableName]
ORDER BY ID
```

You can read more about `LEAD` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: No, `ORDER BY id` is arbitrary, because there can be multiple rows per ID (which is what this is all about). This means the `ORDER BY` for `LEAD` can order the rows differently from the `ORDER BY` for the query result, thus potentially rendering the result wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, Lag(ID) OVER(Order by ID desc) as [NextVal], 
case when 
    Lag(ID) OVER(Order by ID desc) = ID THEN 'yes'
    ELSE 'no'
END as 'FLAG'
from tableName
order by 1 , 2
```

Comment: Funny that you are sing `LAG` on the reverse order instead of `LEAD` right away. The idea to include the lead ID in the query's `ORDER BY` is clever. You still have two `ORDER BY id` in your query, though. While it's reeeally unlikely that the DBMS applies different orders on the two `LAG` expressions, it is still free to do so. So a tiny little risk remains that the result comes out wrong.